# VBA Copying a macro and a worksheet which has a button assigned to the macro to another worksheet

Tags: vba

I have an xlsm file which has a macro and worksheets. I need to copy the macro and a worksheet to a different workbook. Like to know the easiest way to do. Thanks!

Comment: Is it in a sheet, form, or module?

Comment: Module and then created a button to call the macro in a worksheet

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click on the Sheet's tab and create a copy of the sheet in a new workbook.